# Ubuntu 19.10 cannot connect to UniFi Wi-Fi access points

Tags: broadcom, 19.10, wpa-supplicant, wpa2

I can connect to any Wi-Fi networks except for my company corporate Wi-Fi (using UniFi access points). Running Ubuntu 19.10, wpasupplicant 2.9-1ubuntu2.

Wi-Fi chip: Broadcom BCM4350
I tried with a TP-Link USB Wi-Fi adapter (Ralink RT5572 chipset) and it seems to work.

Any clue why or how I should proceed with debugging or bug reporting to Broadcom or Linux kernel developers? How do I know if it's an issue with the `brcmfmac` driver or with wpa_supplicant?

Getting this error message in /var/log/syslog:

```
ctrl-event-assoc-reject bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 status_code=16
```

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. BCM4350 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 256 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 58
    Region 0: Memory at 92400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Region 2: Memory at 92000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: brcmfmac
    Kernel modules: brcmfmac

dataviruset@dataviruset-MacBookPro:~$ dpkg -l wpasupplicant
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version        Architecture Description
+++-==============-==============-============-==============================================
ii  wpasupplicant  2:2.9-1ubuntu2 amd64        client support for WPA and WPA2 (IEEE 802.11i)


dataviruset@dataviruset-MacBookPro:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=31 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

enp0s20f0u8u4  no wireless extensions.

dataviruset@dataviruset-MacBookPro:~$ modinfo brcmfmac
filename:       /lib/modules/5.3.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/broadcom/brcm80211/brcmfmac/brcmfmac.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Broadcom 802.11 wireless LAN fullmac driver.
author:         Broadcom Corporation
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43012-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4373-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4356-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4354-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43456-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43430a0-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4339-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43362-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4335-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43340-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4334-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4330-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4329-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43241b5-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43241b4-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43241b0-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43143-sdio.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4373.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43569.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43242a.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43236b.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43143.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4371-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4366c-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4366b-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4365c-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4365b-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4359-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4358-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43570-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4356-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4350c2-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac4350-pcie.bin
firmware:       brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin
srcversion:     D85FBD42B83F14EACF66C92
alias:          usb:v04B4p0BDCd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A5Cp0BDCd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v043Ep3101d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v04B4pBD29d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v13B1p0039d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A5CpBD27d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A5CpBD1Fd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A5CpBD17d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0A5CpBD1Ed*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000440Dsv*sd*bc02sc80i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000043C5sv*sd*bc02sc80i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000043C4sv*sd*bc02sc80i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000043C3sv*sd*bc02sc80i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004365sv000014E4sd00004365bc02sc80i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000043CCsv*sd*bc02sc80i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000043CBsv*sd*bc02sc80i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000043CAsv*sd*bc02sc80i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d0000AA52sv*sd*bc02sc80i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000043BCsv*sd*bc02sc80i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000043BBsv*sd*bc02sc80i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000043BAsv*sd*bc02sc80i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000043EFsv*sd*bc02sc80i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000043E9sv*sd*bc02sc80i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000043D9sv*sd*bc02sc80i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000043D3sv*sd*bc02sc80i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000043ECsv*sd*bc02sc80i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004354sv*sd*bc02sc80i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d00004355sv000014E4sd00004355bc02sc80i*
alias:          pci:v000014E4d000043A3sv*sd*bc02sc80i*
alias:          sdio:c*v02D0dA804*
alias:          sdio:c*v02D0d4373*
alias:          sdio:c*v02D0d4356*
alias:          sdio:c*v02D0d4354*
alias:          sdio:c*v02D0dA9BF*
alias:          sdio:c*v02D0d4345*
alias:          sdio:c*v02D0dA9A6*
alias:          sdio:c*v02D0d4339*
alias:          sdio:c*v02D0d4335*
alias:          sdio:c*v02D0dA9A4*
alias:          sdio:c*v02D0dA962*
alias:          sdio:c*v02D0dA94D*
alias:          sdio:c*v02D0dA94C*
alias:          sdio:c*v02D0d4334*
alias:          sdio:c*v02D0d4330*
alias:          sdio:c*v02D0d4329*
alias:          sdio:c*v02D0d4324*
alias:          sdio:c*v02D0dA887*
depends:        brcmutil,cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           brcmfmac
vermagic:       5.3.0-29-generic SMP mod_unload 
sig_id:         PKCS#7
signer:         Build time autogenerated kernel key
sig_key:        5B:A4:37:5A:64:28:0B:8F:ED:71:C0:A1:4B:B6:F3:76:64:5C:8D:F4
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
signature:      63:16:70:B9:15:B1:ED:06:E7:BD:68:4D:82:A3:34:6B:9C:B2:9B:A9:
        12:81:DA:5D:C1:A6:F3:FC:49:6F:61:93:A9:A5:3F:A6:57:19:BC:2F:
[..]
        4E:4B:FA:EB:54:A2:39:E1:94:62:20:48:4B:93:D7:F1:CE:90:D1:EF:
        1A:C9:AB:DD:66:CD:1A:14:E2:57:F3:10:E7:57:10:B6:7A:06:54:0B:
        48:B2:A4:FA:A4:34:10:93:A9:EE:71:63
parm:           txglomsz:Maximum tx packet chain size [SDIO] (int)
parm:           debug:Level of debug output (int)
parm:           p2pon:Enable legacy p2p management functionality (int)
parm:           feature_disable:Disable features (int)
parm:           alternative_fw_path:Alternative firmware path (string)
parm:           fcmode:Mode of firmware signalled flow control (int)
parm:           roamoff:Do not use internal roaming engine (int)
parm:           iapp:Enable partial support for the obsoleted Inter-Access Point Protocol (int)



dataviruset@dataviruset-MacBookPro:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan


dataviruset@dataviruset-MacBookPro:~$ uname -a
Linux dataviruset-MacBookPro 5.3.0-29-generic #31-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 17 17:27:26 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

After adding `-dd` to my wpa_supplicant launch options:

```
nl80211: Scan SSID MySecretCompanyHQ
nl80211: Scan SSID
nl80211: Scan extra IEs - hexdump(len=126): dd 69 00 50 f2 04 10 4a 00 01 10 10 3a 00 01 00 10 08 00 02 31 48 10 47 00 10 56 1d 28 90 7c 7a 58 8e be 00 90 ea e8 de 90 e1 10 54 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 3c 00 01 03 10 02 00 02 00 00 10 09 00 02 00 00 10 12 00 02 00 00 10 21 00 01 20 10 23 00 01 20 10 24 00 01 20 10 11 00 01 20 10 49 00 06 00 37 2a 00 01 20 dd 11 50 6f 9a 09 02 02 00 25 00 06 05 00 58 58 04 51 0b
Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 30 seconds
nl80211: Event message available
nl80211: Ignored event 33 (NL80211_CMD_TRIGGER_SCAN) for foreign interface (ifindex 2 wdev 0x0)
nl80211: Drv Event 33 (NL80211_CMD_TRIGGER_SCAN) received for wlp2s0
wlp2s0: nl80211: Scan trigger
wlp2s0: Event SCAN_STARTED (47) received
wlp2s0: Own scan request started a scan in 0.000140 seconds
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=2 ifname=wlp2s0 wext ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
nl80211: Event message available
nl80211: Ignored event 34 (NL80211_CMD_NEW_SCAN_RESULTS) for foreign interface (ifindex 2 wdev 0x0)
nl80211: Drv Event 34 (NL80211_CMD_NEW_SCAN_RESULTS) received for wlp2s0
wlp2s0: nl80211: New scan results available
nl80211: Scan probed for SSID 'MySecretCompanyHQ'
nl80211: Scan probed for SSID ''
nl80211: Scan included frequencies: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472 5180 5190 5200 5210 5220 5230 5240 5260 5280 5300 5320 5500 5520 5540 5560 5580 5600 5620 5640 5660 5680 5700 5745 5765 5785 5805 5825
wlp2s0: Event SCAN_RESULTS (3) received
wlp2s0: Scan completed in 2.193411 seconds
nl80211: Received scan results (94 BSSes)
wlp2s0: BSS: Start scan result update 6
wlp2s0: BSS: Add new id 100 BSSID 96:83:c2:76:1d:38 SSID 'MySecretCompanyHQ-AV' freq 2412
dbus: Register BSS object '/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/100'
wlp2s0: BSS: Add new id 101 BSSID 74:83:c2:75:fe:0b SSID 'MySecretCompanyHQ' freq 2462
dbus: Register BSS object '/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/101'
wlp2s0: BSS: Add new id 102 BSSID a6:83:c2:16:2b:a8 SSID '' freq 2412
dbus: Register BSS object '/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/102'
wlp2s0: BSS: Add new id 103 BSSID 8e:dc:96:70:c0:05 SSID 'TPHK-02' freq 5240
dbus: Register BSS object '/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/103'
BSS: last_scan_res_used=93/128
wlp2s0: New scan results available (own=1 ext=0)
WPS: AP[0] b0:6e:bf:9e:64:80 type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago blacklist=0
WPS: AP[1] 1c:bf:ce:2e:76:ea type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago blacklist=0
WPS: AP[2] 8a:03:55:91:cf:43 type=0 tries=0 last_attempt=-1 sec ago blacklist=0
wlp2s0: Radio work 'scan'@0x56432b8ae060 done in 2.201383 seconds
wlp2s0: radio_work_free('scan'@0x56432b8ae060): num_active_works --> 0
wlp2s0: Selecting BSS from priority group 0
wlp2s0: 0: 74:83:c2:73:fe:cd ssid='MySecretCompanyHQ' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=24 caps=0x1511 level=-43 freq=5560
wlp2s0:    skip - blacklisted (count=1 limit=0)
wlp2s0: 1: 76:83:c2:73:fe:cd ssid='MySecretCompanyHQ-Guest' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=24 caps=0x1511 level=-44 freq=5560
wlp2s0:    skip - SSID mismatch
wlp2s0: 2: 86:83:c2:73:fe:cd ssid='MySecretCompanyHQ-AV' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=20 caps=0x511 level=-44 freq=5560
wlp2s0:    skip - SSID mismatch
wlp2s0: 3: 96:83:c2:73:fe:cd ssid='MySecretCompanyHQ-FN' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=24 caps=0x1511 level=-44 freq=5560
wlp2s0:    skip - SSID mismatch
wlp2s0: 4: a6:83:c2:73:fe:cd ssid='' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=20 caps=0x511 level=-44 freq=5560
wlp2s0:    skip - SSID not known
wlp2s0: 5: b6:83:c2:73:fe:cd ssid='' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=20 caps=0x511 level=-49 freq=5560
wlp2s0:    skip - SSID not known
wlp2s0: 6: 74:83:c2:18:4c:03 ssid='MySecretCompanyHQ' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=24 caps=0x1511 level=-55 freq=5680
wlp2s0:    skip - blacklisted (count=1 limit=0)
wlp2s0: 7: 76:83:c2:18:4c:03 ssid='MySecretCompanyHQ-Guest' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=24 caps=0x1511 level=-55 freq=5680
wlp2s0:    skip - SSID mismatch
wlp2s0: 8: 86:83:c2:18:4c:03 ssid='MySecretCompanyHQ-AV' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=20 caps=0x511 level=-55 freq=5680
wlp2s0:    skip - SSID mismatch
wlp2s0: 9: 96:83:c2:18:4c:03 ssid='MySecretCompanyHQ-FN' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=24 caps=0x1511 level=-56 freq=5680
wlp2s0:    skip - SSID mismatch
wlp2s0: 10: b6:83:c2:18:4c:03 ssid='' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=20 caps=0x511 level=-56 freq=5680
wlp2s0:    skip - SSID not known
wlp2s0: 11: a6:83:c2:18:4c:03 ssid='' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=20 caps=0x511 level=-56 freq=5680
wlp2s0:    skip - SSID not known
wlp2s0: 12: 76:83:c2:18:45:d7 ssid='MySecretCompanyHQ-Guest' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=24 caps=0x1511 level=-63 freq=5500
wlp2s0:    skip - SSID mismatch
wlp2s0: 13: 74:83:c2:18:45:d7 ssid='MySecretCompanyHQ' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=24 caps=0x1511 level=-63 freq=5500
wlp2s0:    skip - blacklisted (count=1 limit=0)
wlp2s0: 14: 86:83:c2:18:45:d7 ssid='MySecretCompanyHQ-AV' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=20 caps=0x511 level=-63 freq=5500
wlp2s0:    skip - SSID mismatch
wlp2s0: 15: 96:83:c2:18:45:d7 ssid='MySecretCompanyHQ-FN' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=24 caps=0x1511 level=-63 freq=5500
wlp2s0:    skip - SSID mismatch
wlp2s0: 16: a6:83:c2:18:45:d7 ssid='' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=20 caps=0x511 level=-64 freq=5500
wlp2s0:    skip - SSID not known
wlp2s0: 17: b6:6e:bf:9e:64:80 ssid='KitchenGuest' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=20 caps=0x411 level=0 freq=2437
wlp2s0:    skip - SSID mismatch
wlp2s0: 18: 86:83:c2:79:85:56 ssid='MySecretCompanyHQ-AV' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=20 caps=0x431 level=0 freq=2412
wlp2s0:    skip - SSID mismatch
wlp2s0: 19: 74:83:c2:79:91:4a ssid='MySecretCompanyHQ' wpa_ie_len=0 rsn_ie_len=24 caps=0x1431 level=0 freq=2412
wlp2s0:    selected based on RSN IE
wlp2s0:    selected BSS 74:83:c2:79:91:4a ssid='MySecretCompanyHQ'
wlp2s0: Considering connect request: reassociate: 0  selected: 74:83:c2:79:91:4a  bssid: 00:00:00:00:00:00  pending: 00:00:00:00:00:00  wpa_state: SCANNING  ssid=0x56432b871d60  current_ssid=(nil)
wlp2s0: Request association with 74:83:c2:79:91:4a
wlp2s0: Re-association to the same ESS
TDLS: TDLS is allowed in the target BSS
TDLS: TDLS channel switch allowed in the target BSS
wlp2s0: No ongoing scan/p2p-scan found to abort
wlp2s0: Add radio work 'connect'@0x56432b8ae060
wlp2s0: First radio work item in the queue - schedule start immediately
RSN: Ignored PMKID candidate without preauth flag
RSN: Ignored PMKID candidate without preauth flag
RSN: Ignored PMKID candidate without preauth flag
RSN: Ignored PMKID candidate without preauth flag
RSN: Ignored PMKID candidate without preauth flag
RSN: Ignored PMKID candidate without preauth flag
RSN: Ignored PMKID candidate without preauth flag
RSN: Ignored PMKID candidate without preauth flag
RSN: Ignored PMKID candidate without preauth flag
RSN: Ignored PMKID candidate without preauth flag
RSN: Ignored PMKID candidate without preauth flag
RSN: Ignored PMKID candidate without preauth flag
RSN: Ignored PMKID candidate without preauth flag
RSN: Ignored PMKID candidate without preauth flag
p2p-dev-wlp2s0: Updating scan results from sibling
nl80211: Received scan results (94 BSSes)
p2p-dev-wlp2s0: BSS: Start scan result update 6
p2p-dev-wlp2s0: BSS: Add new id 100 BSSID 96:83:c2:76:1d:38 SSID 'MySecretCompanyHQ-AV' freq 2412
p2p-dev-wlp2s0: BSS: Add new id 101 BSSID 74:83:c2:75:fe:0b SSID 'MySecretCompanyHQ' freq 2462
p2p-dev-wlp2s0: BSS: Add new id 102 BSSID a6:83:c2:16:2b:a8 SSID '' freq 2412
p2p-dev-wlp2s0: BSS: Add new id 103 BSSID 8e:dc:96:70:c0:05 SSID 'TPHK-02' freq 5240
BSS: last_scan_res_used=93/128
dbus: flush_object_timeout_handler: Timeout - sending changed properties of object /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/3
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/0
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/1
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/2
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/89
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/60
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/5
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/6
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/4
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/7
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/61
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/78
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/11
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/8
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/12
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/9
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/13
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/24
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/36
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/32
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/14
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/62
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/90
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/16
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/17
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/63
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/20
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/80
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/91
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/79
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/54
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/22
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/64
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/19
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/23
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/25
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/26
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/28
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/58
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/65
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/66
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/82
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/81
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/84
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/83
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/92
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/93
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/57
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/85
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/31
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/67
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/86
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/94
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/33
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/50
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/70
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/69
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/95
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/37
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/68
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/72
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/39
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/49
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/38
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/40
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/41
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/71
dbus: flush_object_timeout_handler: Timeout - sending changed properties of object /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/96
wlp2s0: Starting radio work 'connect'@0x56432b8ae060 after 0.016998 second wait
wlp2s0: Trying to associate with SSID 'MySecretCompanyHQ'
wlp2s0: Cancelling scan request
wlp2s0: WPA: clearing own WPA/RSN IE
RSN: PMKSA cache search - network_ctx=0x56432b871d60 try_opportunistic=0 akmp=0x0
RSN: Search for BSSID 74:83:c2:79:91:4a
RSN: No PMKSA cache entry found
wlp2s0: RSN: using IEEE 802.11i/D9.0
wlp2s0: WPA: Selected cipher suites: group 16 pairwise 16 key_mgmt 66 proto 2
wlp2s0: WPA: Selected mgmt group cipher 32
wlp2s0: WPA: clearing AP WPA IE
WPA: set AP RSN IE - hexdump(len=26): 30 18 01 00 00 0f ac 04 01 00 00 0f ac 04 02 00 00 0f ac 02 00 0f ac 04 00 00
wlp2s0: WPA: AP group 0x10 network profile group 0x18; available group 0x10
wlp2s0: WPA: using GTK CCMP
wlp2s0: WPA: AP pairwise 0x10 network profile pairwise 0x18; available pairwise 0x10
wlp2s0: WPA: using PTK CCMP
wlp2s0: WPA: AP key_mgmt 0x42 network profile key_mgmt 0x142; available key_mgmt 0x42
wlp2s0: WPA: using KEY_MGMT FT/PSK
wlp2s0: WPA: AP mgmt_group_cipher 0x20 network profile mgmt_group_cipher 0x0; available mgmt_group_cipher 0x0
wlp2s0: WPA: not using MGMT group cipher
WPA: Set own WPA IE default - hexdump(len=22): 30 14 01 00 00 0f ac 04 01 00 00 0f ac 04 01 00 00 0f ac 04 80 00
PSK (set in config) - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
WPA: Set PMK based on external data - hexdump(len=32): [REMOVED]
wlp2s0: Automatic auth_alg selection: 0x1
Added supported operating classes IE - hexdump(len=22): 3b 14 51 51 53 54 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7a 7b 7c 7d 7e 7f 80 81 82
wlp2s0: State: SCANNING -> ASSOCIATING
nl80211: Set wlp2s0 operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=2 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=5 (IF_OPER_DORMANT)
wlp2s0: Determining shared radio frequencies (max len 2)
wlp2s0: Shared frequencies (len=0): completed iteration
P2P: Add operating class 81
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=13): 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b 0c 0d
P2P: Add operating class 115
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 24 28 2c 30
P2P: Add operating class 116
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 24 2c
P2P: Add operating class 117
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 28 30
P2P: Add operating class 124
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 95 99 9d a1
P2P: Add operating class 125
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=5): 95 99 9d a1 a5
P2P: Add operating class 126
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 95 9d
P2P: Add operating class 127
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=2): 99 a1
P2P: Add operating class 128
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 24 28 2c 30
P2P: Add operating class 130
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=4): 24 28 2c 30
P2P: Update channel list
P2P: channels: 81:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13 115:36,40,44,48 116:36,44 117:40,48 124:149,153,157,161 125:149,153,157,161,165 126:149,157 127:153,161 128:36,40,44,48 130:36,40,44,48
P2P: cli_channels:
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 2 iftype 2 (STATION)
nl80211: Unsubscribe mgmt frames handle 0x8888decba30a5559 (mode change)
nl80211: Subscribe to mgmt frames with non-AP handle 0x56432b82ddd0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x56432b82ddd0 match=0104
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x56432b82ddd0 match=040a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x56432b82ddd0 match=040b
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x56432b82ddd0 match=040c
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x56432b82ddd0 match=040d
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x56432b82ddd0 match=090a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x56432b82ddd0 match=090b
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x56432b82ddd0 match=090c
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x56432b82ddd0 match=090d
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x56432b82ddd0 match=0409506f9a09
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x56432b82ddd0 match=7f506f9a09
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x56432b82ddd0 match=0409506f9a1a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x56432b82ddd0 match=0801
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x56432b82ddd0 match=12
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x56432b82ddd0 match=06
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x56432b82ddd0 match=0a07
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x56432b82ddd0 match=0a11
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x56432b82ddd0 match=0a1a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x56432b82ddd0 match=1101
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x56432b82ddd0 match=1102
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x56432b82ddd0 match=0505
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x56432b82ddd0 match=0500
nl80211: Key management set PSK
nl80211: Connect (ifindex=2)
  * bssid_hint=74:83:c2:79:91:4a
  * freq_hint=2412
  * SSID=MySecretCompanyHQ
  * IEs - hexdump(len=44): 30 14 01 00 00 0f ac 04 01 00 00 0f ac 04 01 00 00 0f ac 04 80 00 3b 14 51 51 53 54 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 7a 7b 7c 7d 7e 7f 80 81 82
  * WPA Versions 0x2
  * pairwise=0xfac04
  * group=0xfac04
  * akm=0xfac04
  * htcaps - hexdump(len=26): 63 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  * htcaps_mask - hexdump(len=26): 63 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  * vhtcaps - hexdump(len=12): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  * vhtcaps_mask - hexdump(len=12): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  * Auth Type 0
nl80211: Connect request send successfully
wlp2s0: Setting authentication timeout: 10 sec 0 usec
EAPOL: External notification - EAP success=0
EAPOL: External notification - EAP fail=0
EAPOL: External notification - portControl=Auto
[...] /fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/74
dbus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.GetAll (/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/100) [s]
dbus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.GetAll (/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/101) [s]
dbus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.GetAll (/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/102) [s]
dbus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.GetAll (/fi/w1/wpa_supplicant1/Interfaces/0/BSSs/103) [s]
nl80211: Event message available
nl80211: Ignored event 46 (NL80211_CMD_CONNECT) for foreign interface (ifindex 2 wdev 0x0)
nl80211: Drv Event 46 (NL80211_CMD_CONNECT) received for wlp2s0
nl80211: Connect event (status=16 ignore_next_local_disconnect=0)
wlp2s0: Event ASSOC_REJECT (12) received
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT bssid=00:00:00:00:00:00 status_code=16
wlp2s0: Radio work 'connect'@0x56432b8ae060 done in 2.879675 seconds
wlp2s0: radio_work_free('connect'@0x56432b8ae060): num_active_works --> 0
Added BSSID 74:83:c2:79:91:4a into blacklist
wlp2s0: Blacklist count 1 --> request scan in 100 ms
wlp2s0: Setting scan request: 0.100000 sec
nl80211: Data frame filter flags=0x0
wlp2s0: State: ASSOCIATING -> DISCONNECTED
```